# How do I identify a Faktor-IPS extension property in a validation message?

Tags: ide-customization, faktor-ips

I've created an extension property and added some validation code - but how do I identify the extension property within the message so the error marker is placed on the field for my extension property?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public MessageList validate(IIpsObjectPartContainer ipsObjectPart, Object value) throws CoreException {
        MessageList ml = new MessageList();
        
        if (!(value instanceof Bearbeitbarkeit)) {
            ml.newError(MSG_WRONG_TYPE, "Der Typ des Werts passt nicht zum Extension Property", ipsObjectPart);
        }
        
        return ml;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the qualified extension point ID ('<your contributing plugin's ID>.<your extension point's ID>' as an additional parameter to the newError-method.
The ExtensionPropertyControlFactory uses that ID to bind the UI elements to the ipsObjectPart.